# Reading a file auto-repeatedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Using Visual Studio 2012 C#, I will make a program to open and read a text file within some periods auto-repeatedly.

Like this auto-repeat action, what kind of features should i use to be smooth process ? In this meantime, the other program will write this text file as well ?

Background worker ? any more suitable?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most effective way is to use timer. When timer fires you can use background worker to open text file and do some work then.